# How to close details tag when other is open or a click is made outside the tag

Tags: html, html-tag-details

this code below almost does the trick. If you open any details tag and then click anywhere outside of it it will close. However, currently open details tags wont close as a new details tag is open.

```js
var details = [...document.querySelectorAll('details')];
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!details.some(f => f.contains(e.target))) {
    details.forEach(f => f.removeAttribute('open'));
  }
})
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Details 1</summary>
  <p>content</p>
</details>

<details>
  <summary>Details 2</summary>
  <p>content</p>
</details>

<details>
  <summary>Details 3</summary>
  <p>content</p>
</details>
```

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check whether the target is a `details` tag, and if not, close all `details` tags.

If it is, only close the ones that don't have the event target as a child.

```js
var details = [...document.querySelectorAll('details')];
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!details.some(f => f.contains(e.target))) {
    details.forEach(f => f.removeAttribute('open'));
  } else {
    details.forEach(f => !f.contains(e.target) ? f.removeAttribute('open') : '');
  }
})
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Details 1</summary>
  <p>content</p>
</details>

<details>
  <summary>Details 2</summary>
  <p>content</p>
</details>

<details>
  <summary>Details 3</summary>
  <p>content</p>
</details>
```

Comment: why did you delete your previous answer? It seemed to work fine just by removing the condition as you said.

Comment: Oh, I see why now. With the previous one the tag will close even if you click inside of it. This new one seems to go around that too. thank you.